# Path Question for Kohana

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana

I am newbie to Kohana (v3 used).
When I run the Hello World example.
If I link to another css file, the css doesn't work.

Original example works well.

Let's go and make the view file application/views/site.php for our message:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>We've got a message for you!</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {font-family: Georgia;}
            h1 {font-style: italic;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php echo $message; ?></h1>
        <p>We just wanted to say it! :)</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I changed the Css to another file like this. and I placed the default.css at the same directory of application/views/default.css
Instead the current ... with default.css. It doesn't work! ? Could you tell me why and how to fix it. Thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>We've got a message for you!</title>
        <LINK href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php echo $message; ?></h1>
        <p>We just wanted to say it! :)</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

update.

The Logo.gif also can't show up. 
And i created a new folder 'images' and placed a Logo.gif in it.
like ths **application/views/images/Logo.gif**

application/views/site.php

```
 <div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
   <p><img src="../index.php/images/Logo.gif" alt=""/></p>
   <h1><?php echo $message; ?></a></h1>
   <h2>We just wanted to say it! :)</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
```

What's wrong with it? Thanks for reading and replies.

Comment: Where is default.css in relation to your php file?

Comment: Hi Vincent, I just update post. The default.css located at the same folder as site.php. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way kohana works may take some getting used to. First, place your css in a directory under the root like this:

```
   media/css/default.css
```

Next, edit the template file: **application/views/template.php**

```
  <?php echo html::stylesheet(
  array
  (
    'media/css/default',
  ),
  array
  (
    'screen',
   )
 );
 ?>
```

You do not need to add the link to the HTML. The framework will add the link for you using the template.

[This page](http://dev.kohanaphp.com/wiki/kohana2/Kohana101#Get-Stylish) gives a few more details about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has changed to

```
echo html::style('/media/css/styles.css');
```

On newer Kohana versions.